# Sort fetched json data(from mongoDB) according to months(MERN)

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, mongodb, fetch-api

I want to change the order of data according to month key given in data.

This is my data i am fetching from ***http://localhost:8080/api/allFests/***

```
{

"success": true,

"data": [

    

{
"festMonth": "February",
"festImage": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.q1sF3Eu_WEz8age76TeQKwHaF7?w=229&h=183&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7",
"_id": "60c5ba68161a104008fd42be",
"festTitle": "Vasant Panchami",

"__v": 0
},

{
"festMonth": "April",
"festImage": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP._j1uMAIRJV0he0nkvtaQgQHaFj?w=239&h=180&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7",
"_id": "60c5bbc1161a104008fd42c0",
"festTitle": "\"Rama Navami",

"__v": 0
},

{
"festMonth": "March",
"festImage": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.r8CRWF-lF47McLatXHeb1QHaFj?w=205&h=180&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7",
"_id": "60c5bab6161a104008fd42bf",
"festTitle": "Holi",

"__v": 0
}

]

}
```

So here I have **festMonth**  and it can have values January ,February....December.

In my frontend I want to show first January then february ......Then December data.
(i.e. Sort according to month)

***Till now,It is shown as in database :
i.e.
First February card then April Card and then March card.***

This is my fetching method:

App.js:

```
 const [fests,setFests]=useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/allFests")
      .then((res) => {
        setFests(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

This is my return function on same page:

```
<div className="map_main_div">


    {fests.map((item) => {
                  return (
            <div className="fest_div" key={item._id} style={{listStyle:"none"}}>

     <Card 

     className={classes.root} key={item.id}  >
                    <CardHeader
                      avatar={
                   <Avatar aria-label="recipe"                     className={classes.avatar}>
                        </Avatar>
                      }
               
                      title={item.festTitle}
                      subheader={item.festMonth}
                    />
                                    
                 
                  </Card>
                 </div>

                  );
                })}
                 </div>
```

And this is my route in route.js:

```
router.get('/allFests',async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const allFest=await FestModel.find()
        if(allFest)
        {
            res.status(200).json({
                success:true,
                data:allFest
            })
        }
        else{
            res.status(400).json({
                success:false,
                error:"no fest found"
            })  
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: err.message
        })
    }
}
```

So How can I do this sorting according to months.

Also Is it possible to change order of data in mongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all month names in a list and then sort based on this list.

```js
const data = [ { "festMonth": "February", "festImage": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.q1sF3Eu_WEz8age76TeQKwHaF7?w=229&h=183&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7", "_id": "60c5ba68161a104008fd42be", "festTitle": "Vasant Panchami", "__v": 0 }, { "festMonth": "April", "festImage":
"https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP._j1uMAIRJV0he0nkvtaQgQHaFj?w=239&h=180&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7", "_id": "60c5bbc1161a104008fd42c0", "festTitle": "\"Rama Navami", "__v": 0 }, { "festMonth": "March", "festImage": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.r8CRWF-lF47McLatXHeb1QHaFj?w=205&h=180&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7",
"_id": "60c5bab6161a104008fd42bf", "festTitle": "Holi", "__v": 0 } ],
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

data.sort((a,b) => months.indexOf(a.festMonth) - months.indexOf(b.festMonth));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is the use of this line .as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
And should I write this in css file?

Comment: No you don't have to use this style, adding this style moves the output of console to top in its div.